# adding the button to the collapsible set and getting the value of the collapsible element

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a collapsible set dynamically. Like below

```
div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>'+
 row1["name"]+'<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">'+count+'</span></h3></div>';
```

Now i need to add a button to the each collapsible set and upon clicking on the button i need to get the collapsible element content but collapsible list should not expand.

How can i do that?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Example

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/z3hsb/

### Description

What you need to understand here is how to use:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Your current problem is that click event is propagating through button and hitting collapsible, which in turn opens/closes it. It can be prevented with if functions **[stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)** and **[stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)** are used.

### Code

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="List" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
                <div id='ListItem' data-role='collapsible' data-content-theme='b' data-collapsed='true'>
                    <h3><p>Title</p>
                        <div id="button-set">
                            <input type='button'  data-theme='b' value='Settings' data-mini='true' data-inline='true' data-icon='gear' data-icon-pos='top' id="show-content"/>
                        </div>
                    </h3>
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    $('#show-content').on('click', function(e) {       
        alert($('#ListItem').find('h3 p').text());       
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();          
    });    
});
```

#### CSS:

```
#button-set {
    float:right;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gajotres for the answer but i need the content in the collapsible header. If i say with your above demo when i click on settings i required "Title".

Comment: @Gajotres: to be valid HTML I think you should not add tags like `<div>` or `<input>` inside an `<h3>` tag. Also beware that `<input type="button">` will generate it's own `<div.ui-btn>`, so the best way with JQM 1.4 would be to use plain `<a>` tags for additional buttons and call `enhanceWithin` on the buttons, because JQM by default will only enhance the first link.

Comment: @frequent: This is not my original example, if I can recall it correctly it was an example from one of a Beginner previous questions. I just show him how to prevent propagation, for everything else my support cost 100 Eur ;) hehehe

Comment: @Gajotres: ok. nice :-)

Comment: intead of the custom css I recommend to use ui classes intead of this "hard-coded" margins/floats.

use e.g.
`<a href="#my-action" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-inline ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Create New</a>`

Comment: With multiple pages in project the stop/ImmediatePropagation() do head to initial page on executing.